# MYSQL UPDATE not updating correctly

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I just want to say sorry if this is a really easy question but I'm overworked with this site to the point where parts of the code that are working aren't making sense, any help in telling me why this MYSQL UPDATE isn't working would be greatly appreciated

```
mysql_query("UPDATE setlist SET song_artist='$song_artist1' AND song_name='$song_name1' WHERE         song_id='$song_id'");
```

When it does work the value is being entered as a 0 (which I believe would mean NULL but all of the variables are working correctly as I have used a die statement with the variables inputted into it, I am also not generating any errors from mysql_error, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

This is my MYSQL table setout.

song_id

song_artist

song_name

Comment: Why are you using string interpolation to build SQL in 2013?

Comment: This is the way I was taught it, I haven't done much research on new versions of SQL

Comment: Also post your table schema.

Comment: You were taught wrong (or taught a long time ago). You're a programmer, you're supposed to keep your skills updated and you're supposed to be continually learning, that's just part of the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace AND with a comma,should work.

```
'$song_id'
```

remove the quotes.

Comment: Still receiving the same problem as before, the comma has not worked.

Comment: Could you be more clear about this error?Also,is your id a string?I doubt it.

Comment: Getting the same type of output as before, still not updating the tables information.

Comment: make sure the tablename, collumns and variables excists because apart from that the query should work (with the replacement of the , for the AND). put error_reporting(E_ALL); above the script to see the actual errors

Comment: When I removed the quotations it worked correctly, although I thought for string values, variables needed quotation marks, thanks for the help!

Comment: For string yes,but that is a number you don't need quotes.